# regex group not matching

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the regex

```
(\d|(IV|I{0,3})|\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b|\bfour\b)[\w\s]+
```

if I use the sentence

- '1 has wound' - 1 is matched in group 1 as expected
- 'IV has wound' - IV is matched in group 1 as expected

but, the sentence

- 'one has wound' - the word one doesn't get matched in group 1

when i modify the regex as follows

```
(\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b|\bfour\b|\d|(IV|I{0,3}))[\w\s]+
```

the group matches as expected.

So, my question why does changing the order of the group work..

I tried looking up ordering and precedence for regex but couldn't find anything relevant..

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your regex, it should be

```
(\d|(IV|I{1,3})|\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b|\bfour\b)[\w\s
```

Notice it's `I{1,3}`, not `I{0,3}`.

So, because of that, your regex match **zero I**, thus the empty capture group 1